# Get common elements between multiple arrays and common elements between some

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, set

I am trying to get common elements between multiple arrays. It's a bit more complex than simple intersection because I am trying to do something like this:

```
# resources # => array of objects that have an attribute(lines) thats's an array of strings
```

I am trying to find the common lines between all the resources which I can get by doing this

```
resources.map(&:lines).inject(:&)
```

I also need lines that are common between some of the resources with information about which resources the lines are repeated in

```
resource1 # => name: "resource1", lines: ["abc", "def", ghi"]
resource2 # => name: "resource2", lines: ["abc", "jkl", ghi"]
resource3 # => name: "resource3", lines: ["abc", ghi", "jkl"]
```

I need common between all:

```
["abc", "ghi"]
```

Also need common between some without the stuff that is common among all

```
["resource2", "resource3" ]=> ["jkl"]
```

Comment: `a = [5, 6, 8]`, `b = [5, 9, 8, 10]`, `a.intersection(b)` will result in [5, 8]. If this is what you are looking for https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-intersection

Comment: Can you try and rephrase the question a bit? Should the result be `["abc", "ghi"]` or `["jkl"]`?

Comment: @Viktor the result should be specifying what's common between the resources

eg output:

["resource1", "resource2"], "resource3"] => ["abc", "ghi"]

["resource2", "resource3"] => ["jkl"]

The output format can be anything. preferably a hash with keys and values as arraysarrays

Comment: What would be your desired result if the value of `resource1[:lines]` were `["abc", "def", xxx"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an `Array` of  `Hash`es that looks like this:

```
a = [
{name: "resource1", lines: ["abc", "def", "ghi"]},
{name: "resource2", lines: ["abc", "jkl", "ghi"]},
{name: "resource3", lines: ["abc", "ghi", "jkl"]}]
```

Then you could handle the transformation like so:

```
lines = a.each_with_object({}) do |h,obj| 
  h[:lines].each do |line| 
    (obj[[line]] ||= [])<< h[:name]
  end 
end.each_with_object({}) do |a, obj|
  obj.merge!([a.reverse].to_h) {|_,o,n| o.concat(n)}
end
#=>  {["resource1", "resource2", "resource3"]=>["abc", "ghi"], ["resource1"]=>["def"], ["resource2", "resource3"]=>["jkl"]}
```

First we group all the resources by each line as an `Array`:

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |h,obj| 
  h[:lines].each do |line| 
    (obj[[line]] ||= [])<< h[:name]
  end 
end
#=> {["abc"]=>["resource1", "resource2", "resource3"], ["def"]=>["resource1"], "ghi"=>["resource1", "resource2", "resource3"], ["jkl"]=>["resource2", "resource3"]}
```

then reverse and merge them as `Hash`es where duplicate keys result in concatenated Arrays

```
.each_with_object({}) do |a, obj|
  obj.merge!([a.reverse].to_h) {|_,o,n| o.concat(n}
end 
#=>  {["resource1", "resource2", "resource3"]=>["abc", "ghi"], ["resource1"]=>["def"], ["resource2", "resource3"]=>["jkl"]}
```

Comment: Good one, minky. Consider a more interesting example: `arr = [{ name: "resource1", lines: ["abc", "def", "mno", "pqr"] },  { name: "resource2", lines: ["abc", "jkl", "ghi", "pqr"] },  { name: "resource3", lines: ["abc", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"] }]`. I was going to use it in an answer but then saw I would have retraced your ground.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I appreciate the kind remarks however it's monkey with out vowels [Monkey and the Engineer](https://www.dead.net/song/monkey-and-engineer). Although I guess I could get on board with minky, it's very Inspector Clouseau.

Comment: Then, for consistency, it should be ngnrsmnky.

Comment: @CarySwoveland do you also say Froderick?